Keyboard Handler Issues in SwiftUI
I implemented and used the keyboard handler to ensure that the view is not obscured by the keyboard when the keyboard is called using SwiftUI.
However, when you call the keyboard, the views inside the Vstack are automatically adjusted.
What I want is that when the keyboard is called, the button comes up on the keyboard and the other views are fixed in their current position
I used .ignoreSafeArea(.keyboard) to prevent the view from moving, but not all views moved from their current position when the keyboard was called
I'm attaching my current code
import SwiftUI

struct KeyboardUseView: View {
    @State private var message: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            TextField(""
                      , text: $message
                      , prompt: Text("message input field")
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundStyle(.brown)
            )
            .padding(.vertical,12)
            .padding(.horizontal,16)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .stroke()
                    .fill(.brown.gradient)
            )
            .padding(.horizontal,16)
            Spacer()
            Button{
                
            }label: {
                Text("Button")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .fill(.green)
                    )
                    .padding(.horizontal,16)
            }
        }
        .keyboardAdaptive()
    }
}

#Preview {
    KeyboardUseView()
}


KeyboardHandler Code
import SwiftUI
import Combine


final class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    var keyboardWillShowNotification = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
    var keyboardWillHideNotification = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)

    init() {
        keyboardWillShowNotification.map { notification in
            CGFloat((notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)?.height ?? 0)
        }
        .assign(to: \.currentHeight, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellableSet)

        keyboardWillHideNotification.map { _ in
            CGFloat(0)
        }
        .assign(to: \.currentHeight, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }

    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
}


